# In eclipse, how can I see where the java classes are loaded from?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, runtime

My problem is as follow : I am developing an eclipse plugin and sometimes I lose track of where the classes are loaded from. What I would like is to see in the debugger stacktrace where a class is loaded from (which jar on the harddrive).

Am I missing some obvious Eclipse option ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see location of classes loaded : In Run configurations -> Arguments tab add vm argument -verbose. That will include the full path of classes loaded.

**EDIT:**
To find a particular class from a list of jars:

I use a jar class finder plugin. I do not recall the exact location from where i downloaded, the [alphaworks link](http://alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/jarclassfinder) seems broken as of now. But you can find [similar](http://www.google.com/search?q=jar+class+finder) tools.

Note : In eclipse, if the console fills up to a point you are not able to see previous logs, then in Common tab -> Standard I/O check File option.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It does not give the info as I expected, but it definitly solved my problem. (console is ugly though).
Thanks again !

Comment: @vpi are you talking about finding class from referenced libraries?

Comment: I needed to know if some classes where loaded from plugins or from the JRE